# Javascript validation does not work after ajax update on a table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have the below codes. What I do is that when I press on change of my **combo box** I call the below `Ajax`. What this code does is that it's an `ajax function` that calls the `PHP` to repopulate the table body with new contents. The only problem is that the `Javascript validation` does not work after that.

```
$("#vID").change(function() { 
                
    if(this.value >0){
        var selectedVID = this.value;
        var selectedNumber = $('#vID option:selected').text();
        Swal.fire({
                title: '<strong>Loading  .....</strong>',
                type: 'info',
                html: '',
                //timer: 2000,
                onBeforeOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                    
                },    
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                
            url: 'reminder.php',
            data: {vID:selectedVID},
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#vReminderSettings tbody').html("");
                $('#vReminderSettings tbody').append(data);
                
                let timerInterval;
                Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Successfully Loaded',
                        type: 'success',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 300,
                        onBeforeOpen: () => {
                            

                            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                                
                            }, 100)
                        },
                        onClose: () => {
                            clearInterval(timerInterval)
                        }
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Error:'+e.responseText,
                    type: 'warning',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 2000,
                    onBeforeOpen: () => {
                        

                        timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                            
                        }, 100)
                    },
                    onClose: () => {
                        clearInterval(timerInterval)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        
    }
});
```

As you can see I clear the table body

```
$('#vReminderSettings tbody').html("");
and then appen new contents $('#vReminderSettings tbody').append(data);
```

. All this work perfectly fine.

Here are my codes on the table.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">List</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>
                <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">
                    <table id="vReminderSettings" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="datatable-nosort">No.</th>                                               
                                    <th>Distance(km)</th>                                                                                       
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="vReminderSettingsBody">
                            <tr>
                            <td><div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="distance1" class="form-control" min="1000" max="80000" required="" data-validation-containsnumber-regex="(\d)+" data-validation-containsnumber-message="No Characters Allowed, Only Numbers" aria-invalid="false">
                            <small class="help-block"></small></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="existOptionReminder1" id="existOptionReminder1" value="checked">
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="Update" value="Update">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have purposely on the default left this one table row.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">
                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="distance1" class="form-control" min="1000" max="80000" required="" data-validation-containsnumber-regex="(\d)+" data-validation-containsnumber-message="No Characters Allowed, Only Numbers" aria-invalid="false">
                <small class="help-block"></small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="existOptionReminder1" id="existOptionReminder1" value="checked">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This one works perfectly fine. But when I call the `Ajax` to populate the same thing thereafter the data validation is not working. How to rebind or make the `Javascript` work after the `Ajax`?

Comment: can you be more precise .what validation part is not working?

Comment: @SandeepModak sure this part to be very specific <input type="text" name="distance1" class="form-control" min="1000" max="80000" required="" data-validation-containsnumber-regex="(\d)+" data-validation-containsnumber-message="No Characters Allowed, Only Numbers" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: @SandeepModak to be specific when I leave the text box empty or put some characters it does not validate and alert me.

Comment: @SandeepModak any idea how to resolve on this?

Comment: where is the javascript validation code for the input?

Comment: @SandeepModak in the form I it as <form class="m-t-40" style="margin-top: 0px;" class="needs-validation was-validated" action="settings.php" id="settings" method="post" novalidate>

Comment: Then in the include its  <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validation.js"></script> where the customer javascript validation is done cause it show it accodingly with some css

Comment: @SandeepModak I have been reading a lot it say that after ajax call normally the dynamic text field will loose the validation we need to reassign I am keep trying many way to achieve on this.

Comment: post the javascript code where you have put the validation.

Comment: @SandeepModak I think I found the solution I know the issue and problem ready. I will post later let me confirm and run it. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing here that has anything to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.